# Is it possible to hire heroes from another faction during the campaigns?

Tags: might-and-magic-heroes-6

I have been working through the Necropolis campaign and at one point found myself in possession of an opposing town with a lot of creatures ready to be hired.  However, when I went to the Hall of Heroes to hire a hero whose skills would match up with the creatures, I could find no way to hire a hero from a faction other than my own.

During the campaigns, can you hire heroes from opposing factions in Heroes VI?

Comment: I have no idea about campaign, but I know you can in custom games just by picking them from the hall of heroes.

Comment: @MrSmooth - does the list of heroes just scroll left to right in that case?  Or is there a faction button somewhere on the screen (that I might be missing)?

Comment: It just scrolls left to right, with arrows to click to see the ones that don't fit on the screen.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, I don't believe there is.  I would suggest using a hero whose innate skill is not creature related (either something spell related or a non-combat benefit).